# Centering column in table ignoring minus sign

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have the following table created in latex:

```
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
  \begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
    \toprule
    ~& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Heading1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Heading2} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Heading3}\\
    \midrule
    ~& McCraft & Ours & McCraft & Ours & McCraft & Ours \\
    \midrule
    Joy & -0.23 & -0.26 (0.44) & 0.27 & 0.19 (0.52) & 0.14 & -0.24 (0.56) \\
    Twinkle & 0.26 & 0.44 (0.33) & 0.38 & 0.20 (0.50) & 0.25 & 0.24 (0.51) \\
    Blast & -0.43 & -0.24 (0.50) & 0.17 & 0.10 (0.54) & -0.23 & -0.21 (0.51) \\
    Surprise & 0.10 & 0.29 (0.51) & 0.47 & 0.20 (0.54) & -0.13 & 0.04 (0.52) \\
    Gaze & -0.44 & -0.02 (0.51) & 0.50 & 0.12 (0.53) & -0.33 & -0.21 (0.53) \\
    Disgust & -0.20 & -0.18 (0.52) & 0.25 & 0.04 (0.55) & 0.11 & -0.23 (0.57) \\
    Count & -- & 0.95 (0.49) & -- & 0.18 (0.51) & -- & -0.18 (0.51) \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

[image]

How can I align (centering) the numbers ignoring the minus sign? I'm only allowed to use the packages listed [here](https://www.acm.org/publications/taps/accepted-latex-packages).

Comment: Welcome to TeX Stackexchange!

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would align the numbers on their decimal markers, using the machinery of the `dcolumn` package -- which, happily, is in the set of "good" packages.

Note that since `booktabs` is *not* in the set of "good" packages, you mustn't use it in your code. I suggest inserting explicit typographic "top" and "bottom" struts instead.

Don't use `\resizebox` on a `tabular` environment unless you're willing to tolerate wildly inconsistent font sizes in your document. I suggest using a `tabular*` environment instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn} 
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
%% Define a few typographic struts
%% (from code by Claudio Beccari in TeX and TUG News, Vol. 2, 1993)
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.9ex}}         % "top" strut
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-1.2ex]{0pt}{0pt}}   % "bottom" strut
\newcommand\TBstrut{\Tstrut\Bstrut}           % "top and bottom" strut

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\renewcommand\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
         l *{3}{ d{2.2} >{$}r<{$} } }
    \hline
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Heading1\TBstrut} 
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Heading2} 
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Heading3} \\
    \cline{2-3} \cline{4-5} \cline{6-7} 
    & \mc{McCraft\TBstrut} & \mc{Ours} & \mc{McCraft} & \mc{Ours} & \mc{McCraft} & \mc{Ours} \\
    \hline
    Joy     & -0.23 & -0.26\ (0.44) & 0.27 & 0.19\ (0.52) &  0.14 & -0.24\ (0.56)\Tstrut \\
    Twinkle &  0.26 &  0.44\ (0.33) & 0.38 & 0.20\ (0.50) &  0.25 &  0.24\ (0.51) \\
    Blast   & -0.43 & -0.24\ (0.50) & 0.17 & 0.10\ (0.54) & -0.23 & -0.21\ (0.51) \\
    Surprise&  0.10 &  0.29\ (0.51) & 0.47 & 0.20\ (0.54) & -0.13 &  0.04\ (0.52) \\
    Gaze    & -0.44 & -0.02\ (0.51) & 0.50 & 0.12\ (0.53) & -0.33 & -0.21\ (0.53) \\
    Disgust & -0.20 & -0.18\ (0.52) & 0.25 & 0.04\ (0.55) &  0.11 & -0.23\ (0.57) \\[0.5ex]
    Count   &  \mc{--} &  0.95\ (0.49) & \mc{--} & 0.18\ (0.51) &  \mc{--} & -0.18\ (0.51)\Bstrut \\
    \hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can replace each minus sign with `\llap-` (or `\llap{$-$}` if you want a "real" minus sign) so that it does not count towards the width in the alignment calculations.

(But right-alignment would be more suitable for numbers, especially if they can exceed 9.99.)

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked very well. Is there also a possiblity to replace the \llap- with a minus in math mode? That means a little bit larger dash.

Comment: See my edited answer.